# Why does the Greek word ἐντρέπω (entrepo) appear to have nearly opposite meanings?

Tags: greek, luke, contradiction, translation-philosophy, pauline-epistles

Each of the following verses use this Greek word (English translation of it is bolded)--but a glance at them quickly shows that the word has virtually opposite meanings, with either shame or honor, depending on the text and/or context.

> Having yet therefore one son, his wellbeloved, he sent him also last
> unto them, saying, They will **reverence** my son. (Mark 12:6, KJV)
>
> Saying, There was in a city a judge, which feared not God, neither
> **regarded** man: (Luke 18:2, KJV)
>
> And he would not for a while: but afterward he said within himself,
> Though I fear not God, nor **regard** man; (Luke 18:4, KJV)
>
> Then said the lord of the vineyard, What shall I do? I will send my
> beloved son: it may be they will **reverence** him when they see him.
> (Luke 20:13, KJV)
>
> I write not these things to **shame** you, but as my beloved sons I
> warn you. (1 Corinthians 4:14, KJV)
>
> And if any man obey not our word by this epistle, note that man, and
> have no company with him, that he may be **ashamed.** (2 Thessalonians
> 3:14, KJV)
>
> Sound speech, that cannot be condemned; that he that is of the
> contrary part may be **ashamed,** having no evil thing to say of you.
> (Titus 2:8, KJV)
>
> Furthermore we have had fathers of our flesh which corrected us, and
> we gave them **reverence:** shall we not much rather be in subjection
> unto the Father of spirits, and live? (Hebrews 12:9, KJV)

How, then, can one actually discern which of the meanings is more accurate when translating this word to English?  For example, why couldn't Hebrews 12:9 be speaking of **shame,** or why couldn't Titus 2:8 be referring to *reverence?*  What about Luke 20:13--was Jesus saying the men should be *ashamed* when they saw the son?

How can one know which meaning is right when the word seems to have opposite meanings?

Comment: There is one more reference in Matt 21:36 - they will respect my son.

Comment: "And then there’s shame, which has a double face: one, to be sure, is not an evil thing to possess; but there’s the other shame, whose weight crushes whole households. And if the good and the bad shame were easy to distinguish, the word describing them would not be the same." -- Phaedra in Euripides' _Hippolytus_

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky and subtle - all the instances of **ἐντρέπω (entrepó)** are in the middle or passive voice with the exception of 1 Cor 4:14.  Here is the data from BDAG:

1. to cause to turn (in shame), to shame eg, 1 Cor 4:14, 2 Thess 3:14, Titus 2:8
2. to show deference to a person in reference of special staus, turn toward something/someone, have regard for, respect, eg, Matt 21;37, Mark 12:6, Luke 20:13, 18:2, 4, Heb 12:9.

The basic meaning here is the preposition "en" + "τροπή" = to turn toward, or a change, mutation.  Thus, it can mean to turn toward and respect or to turn away from in shame.  The context sets the meaning and distinction.

Note that "respect" only occurs in the Gospels and Hebrews,while Paul uses only the "shame" meaning.

Lastly, the concept of "honor" (τιμάω = value at a price, to reverence) is captured by a very different word in Greek that is distinct from ἐντρέπω (entrepó) = to turn.

Answer (score 3):

> was Jesus saying the men should **be ashamed** when they saw the son?

You seem to have answered your own question. :-) Shaming someone, and being ashamed of someone, are indeed opposites of one another, insofar killing (someone), and being killed (by someone), are as well; one is [active](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_voice), while the other is [passive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice); this can be easily verified by visiting [this wonderful site](http://www.greekdoc.com/bible/nt-poly/mk12.html#v6); notice that all Greek terms are hyperlinked; clicking on [ἐντραπήσονται](http://www.greekdoc.com/bible/lexicon/ent.html#entraphsontai) confirms that we are indeed dealing with the passive, rather than active voice.

> How can one know which meaning is right when the word seems to have opposite meanings?

Because, in Greek, as in English (along with most other Indo-European languages), active and passive voices are expressed differently, thus eliminating any ground for confusion.

Comment: This is little help as all instances of ἐντρέπω (except 1 Cor 4:14) are in the passive voice.

Comment: @Dottard: Yes, and, apparently, the English translator chose to render many of them by the active form of *to revere/regard*, rather than through the passive form of *to shame*, which is *to be ashamed*, though the latter is also the case in at least two instances.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. The question is asking about the meanings "to shame" versus "to revere," but your answer instead talks about the meanings "to shame" versus "to be ashamed." So your answer is talking about something entirely different from what the question is asking about (unless you're saying that there's some kind of equivalence between "to revere" and "to be ashamed"?)

Comment: @TannerSwett: To be ashamed of something, and to revere it or regard it, are more or less synonymous constructions; imagine, for instance, asking someone who's done something bad: *Do you have no shame (of authority figures, parents, God, the law, etc.) ?*, i.e., are you disregarding their authority ?

Answer (score 1):

For the meaning of ἐντρέπω, it is important to look at the lexical meaning of the active, middle, and passive voices. Otherwise, the different meanings are confusing, as shown in with the charts of how it is used.

```
ἐντρέπω 2 aor. pass. ἐνετράπην; 2 fut. pass. ἐντραπήσομαι (Hom.+; pap., LXX, Joseph.). 
1. act.—a. make someone (τινά) ashamed ... 
2. mostly pass.—a. be put to shame, be ashamed ...
b. w. mid. sense turn toward someth. or someone, have regard for, respect τινά
```

Arndt, W., Gingrich, F. W., Danker, F. W., & Bauer, W. (1979). *A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature : a translation and adaption of the fourth revised and augmented edition of Walter Bauer’s Griechisch-deutsches Worterbuch zu den Schrift en des Neuen Testaments und der ubrigen urchristlichen Literatur* (p. 269). Chicago: University of Chicago Press.

Figure 1. Senses of ἐντρέπω in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software)
[image]

Figure 2. How the Septuagint (LXX) translated ἐντρέπω
[image]

P.S. If you want to be confused more, look at the meaning of the word originating from it now in English.

```
en•tro•py  \ˈen-trə-pē\  noun
plural en•tro•pies
[International Scientific Vocabulary 2en- + Greek tropē change, literally, turn, 
from trepein to turn]
(1875)
 1 : a measure of the unavailable energy in a closed thermodynamic system that 
is also usually considered to be a measure of the system’s disorder and that 
is a property of the system’s state and is related to it in such a manner that 
a reversible change in heat in the system produces a change in the measure 
which varies directly with the heat change and inversely with the absolute 
temperature at which the change takes place; broadly : the degree of disorder
 or uncertainty in a system
  2 a : the degradation of the matter and energy in the universe to an ultimate 
state of inert uniformity
  b : a process of degradation or running down or a trend to disorder
 3 : CHAOS, DISORGANIZATION, RANDOMNESS
```

Merriam-Webster, I. (1996). Merriam-Webster’s collegiate dictionary (10th ed.). Springfield, MA: Merriam-Webster.